# CodeIgniter / Ajax . Posting parameters through ajax to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to post some variables to CodeIgniter controller function through ajax but ts resulting in an error message .

**This is my javascript function**

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {

    $('.add_cart').click(function(){
      var quantity = $('#qty').val();
      var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
      var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
      var product_price = $(this).data("price");

      if(quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
          {
           $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/add_product_to_cart",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, quantity:quantity},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('success');
            }
           });
          }
          else
          {
           alert("Please Enter quantity");
          }

        });
      });
```

**Here is my controller function.**

```
    public function add_product_to_cart()
{

    echo $_POST["product_id"];

}
```

But when i track the whole process through firebug .Its giving the error that undefined variable product_id or does not print any thing when i try to echo it as given below.

Here is the screen shot.
[image]

Can somebody help me about how to do this right or is there any special file that you need to include for ajax functions?

Answer (score 2):

Using Codeigniter (version 2 or 3), you should use the following:

```
$product_id = $this->input->post('product_id');
```

Here is the documentation when using inputs in Codeigniter:

[Using Codeigniter  Inputs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html?highlight=post#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data)

**Ajax Request (Debugging):**

If you are running an ajax call, on Chrome go to *Inspector* and look at the ajax requests being sent, this can show you the values that have been sent to the server. (right click on mouse)

```
Inspect -> Network (toggle on XHR)
```

Then use your form to submit an ajax request, and a new item should show on the table in the network tab, click it, go to headers, and scroll down. It will show you all the information you need with your ajax request, and making sure they are being properly sent.

**UPDATE:**

As Kelvin pointed out, you need to update your ajax from method to type on the request.

`method:"POST"` to `type:"POST"`

Comment: actualy it is oke using $_POST, the problem is the post data are not pass well to the controller, there is a problem on his ajax request

Comment: @Kelvin You are correct. The ajax is incorrect. Yeah it is okay using direct server variables, but that's what the framework is there for, security and easy of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/add_product_to_cart",
   type:"POST",
   data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, quantity:quantity},
   success:function(data)
   {
      alert('success');
   }
);
```

in your `method : "POST"` change it to `type: "POST",` ajax doesnt using the same way like html.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var var_data = {product_id:product_id, 
                   product_name:product_name, 
                   product_price:product_price, 
                   quantity:quantity}
   $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/add_product_to_cart",
        type:"POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        async : false,
        data:var_data,
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert('success');
        }
       });
```

in controller function get the post array from var_data

like

```
   $post_data = $this->input->post('var_data',true);
   print_r($post_data);
```

try it like this may be help , change method to type

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('.add_cart').click(function(){
  var quantity = $('#qty').val();
  var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
  var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
  var product_price = $(this).data("price");

  if(quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
   {
       $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/add_product_to_cart",
        method:"POST",
        data:{"product_id":product_id, "product_name":product_name, "product_price":product_price, "quantity":quantity},
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert('success');
        }
       });
      }
      else
      {
       alert("Please Enter quantity");
      }

    });
  });
```

the parameters shoulb be like this 
data:{"product_id":product_id, "product_name":product_name, "product_price":product_price, "quantity":quantity},

Comment: I  think it is like you suggested.